# run powershell in VBA access

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-access

I need to change a string in multiple text files

I have written the script below in ACCESS VBA but the error is TYPE MISMATCH

```
Dim str As String
str = "N=maher"
Call Shell("c:\windows\system32\powershell.exe" - Command("get-content -Path e:\temptest.txt") - Replace(str, "maher", "ali"))
```

Comment: This should work: 
`-Command ("get-content -Path e:\temptest.txt").Replace("maher", "ali")`

Comment: I don't think so. If I had to guess, the `-replace` is intended to be validated in the PowerShell environment, not the VBA one. But the OP didn't told us, so nobody knows.

Comment: Clearly an x-y problem. If you want to replace a string in a file using VBA, involving PowerShell isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for calling PowerShell is way off. Suggestion: get it working from the command line yourself first, and then run from Access (an odd choice: it just makes this more complicated).

A PowerShell script to do this (`.ps1` file) would need to contain something like:

```
Get-Content -Path "E:\temptest.txt" | ForEach-Object { $_ -Replace 'maher', 'ali' } | do-something-with-the-updated-content
```

You need to define:

- What you are replacing (you pass `N=maher` in but then hard code two strings for `Replace`.
- What do to with the strings after doing the replacement (`Get-Content` only reads files).